# Error when cloning from remote TFS repository in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, tfs-2015, git-clone

Help me StackOverflow, you're my only hope!

I am getting the following error when trying to clone a remote Team Foundation Server 2015 repo:

*Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
unable to access "http://[TFS URI]/tfs/[team collection]/[team project]/_git/[repo]/": Recv failure: Connection was reset*

I've been all over StackOverflow, TFS documentation, and google in general looking for a solution. I've tried all of the changes listed online, such as updating my git --global config settings, HTTP proxy settings (unset), Team Explorer global settings, deleting windows credentials, deleting caches, etc. but nothing seems to work. I've updated Visual Studio, reinstalled Git for Windows as well.

I've tried cloning from TFS, cloning in VS Team Explorer, cloning via the command line with both Powershell and WSL2.

My name has been added to the project in TFS with the appropriate permissions as well.

I am behind a company VPN/Firewall, and everyone else on my team does not have this issue. Any help is appreciated!